# Lisp - string concat

Tags: lisp, clisp

I am trying to concat strings in lisp, using clisp on linux.
I run following code:

```
(defun bingo ()
  (strcat "Correct! You guessed " (itoa *count*) " times."))
```

but, get following error:

```
EVAL: undefined function STRCAT
EVAL: undefined function ITOA
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `concatenate` instead of `strcat`

Comment: @bluebelle Thank you, and can you tell which function is used for convert a int to string?

Comment: Now you understand why your question get downvoted don't you? Even I who never programmed in Common Lisp can google the answer myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CL-USER 1 > (format nil "This is too easy. ~a day I'll learn Lisp." 1)
"This is too easy. 1 day I'll learn Lisp."
```